# Does Tomcat support Bearer (Token) Authentication and, if so, how does one configure it?

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, basic-authentication, bearer-token

The system is using Tomcat 5.5.28 (Java Servlet 2.4). I have a randomly generated token I created with HMAC (Hash-based Message Authentication Code). The token will be utilized in a RESTful web service. As I understand it, there is something called Bearer Authentication which involves setting the Authorization HTTP Header to `Bearer {token}, i.e. Bearer ABCD1234`. Does Tomcat support Bearer Authentication and, if so, how do I configure it?

If I can't use Bearer Authentication, then my back-up plan is configure Basic Authentication and pass the token as a custom HTTP Header. Ostensibly, HTTPS will be enforced, specifically TLS, for any type of authentication.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Tomcat 5.5 does not support Bearer Authentication, nor does any later version. You can implement your own authentication by writing a Valve that handles it.

If there's significant interest, such authentication might be supported by Tomcat in the future, but you'll have to get involved and raise popular support. I had never heard of Bearer Authentication before...

There's been some work lately to implement a JASPIC authentication, which will presumably make it easier to do pluggable authentication modules in Tomcat, which might make it easier to implement such a scheme, even if you have to hand-roll it.

Consider joining the Tomcat dev list to ask there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Good stuff. IIRC, Bearer Authentication is also called Token authentication. I believe this is what OAuth utilizes. I suppose my options are use OAuth or, like you said, write my own. Other than OAuth, I am unable to find any Java libraries that offer token authentication for an application server like Tomcat

Comment: @user3621633 as for JASPIC, there's a ready to use JASPIC based token authentication module shown here: http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/11/header-based-stateless-token.html